# Calling DBus methods in Gjs / Gnome Shell

Tags: dbus, gnome-shell, gjs

If I have a bus name, an object path, and an interface, how do I call DBus methods from Gjs (in a gnome-shell extension)?

I'm looking for the equivalent of the following python code:

```py
import dbus
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
obj = bus.get_object("org.gnome.Caribou.Keyboard", "/org/gnome/SessionManager/EndSessionDialog")
obj.Open(0, 0, 120, dbus.Array(signature="o"))
```

(Note that I didn't explicitly use the interface due to some python-dbus magic, but I could have with `iface = dbus.interface(obj, "org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog")`. Since I have the interface name, I'm fine with a solution that queries it. Also note that this example would be silly in Gjs, as it calls back into gnome-shell)

Answer (score 13):

The import `imports.dbus` is deprecated since gnome-shell 3.4.
The new way is to use `Gio` as described [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-shell-list/2013-February/msg00059.html):

```js
const Gio = imports.gi.Gio;

const MyIface = '<interface name="org.example.MyInterface">\
<method name="Activate" />\
</interface>';
const MyProxy = Gio.DBusProxy.makeProxyWrapper(MyIface);

let instance = new MyProxy(Gio.DBus.session, 'org.example.BusName',
'/org/example/Path');
```

(Note that the original post uses `makeProxyClass`, correct is `makeProxyWrapper`.)

You can get the interface definition, for example, by using introspection.
For pidgin/purple do:

```
$ dbus-send --print-reply --dest=im.pidgin.purple.PurpleService \
/im/pidgin/purple/PurpleObject org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect
```

Further explanations on introspection and inspection of interfaces can be found [here](http://cheesehead-techblog.blogspot.de/2012/08/dbus-tutorial-introspection-figuring.html).

Answer (score 1):

this should give you a better idea:

```
gjs> const DBus = imports.dbus;
gjs> for (let i in DBus) log(i);
```